# How to remove all the inline styles on parent Element with the help of child element in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on one angular project, where I want to remove the parent element styling with the help of child element, because the child element is on condition based.
**Note** parent element is having inline styling

my code is something like this

```
<form style="background-color: red; padding: 5px"
 class="my-form">
<div>
<div>
  <button class="my-btn">click me</button>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.my-btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you got a reference tot the button element in your code? Have you figured out how to get the parent from that? Have you figured out how to clear the `style` attribute?

Comment: what have you tried so far and where you struggle at?

Comment: doesn't: `parent child + parent {}` work?

Comment: @JelleStekelenburg: No, CSS selector work top-down.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to remove the background setting in the form element or do you just want the button' s background to cover it up?

Answer (score 0):

While a child element cannot directly influence the styling of a parent there are some things you can do, but whether these ideas are useful depends on exactly what you want to do.

Taking the code given in the question it is possible to make it look as though the background color of the form has been changed by putting a pseudo element on the btn which is positioned absolutely and sized relative to the form, not to the btn. CSS variables can be set on the btn element and then picked up by its pseudo element, as the background color is here for example.

```css
.my-form {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: -2;
}

.my-btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-btn::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: var(--bg);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<form style="background-color: red; padding: 5px" class="my-form">
  <div>
    <div>
      <button class="my-btn" style="--bg: blue;">click me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```